# Problema al añadir una tabla de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

resulta que quiero crear una tabla desde JavaScript y hasta ahora iba todo bien pero cuando quize colocar algunos data en el input cuando voy a ver el codigo HTML aparecen de forma que no es adecuada y no permiten el funcionamiento. A continuación el codigo del input en en javascript

```
<input type='button' name='btnEditarProduct' value='Editar' class='btn btn-outline-dark btnEditarProduct' data-toggle='modal' data-id=".$result['product_id']." data-name=".$result['product_name']." data-reference=".$result['reference']." data-desc=".$result['product_desc']." data-price=".$result['product_price']." data-talla=".$result['product_talla']." data-cate=".$result['product_cate']." data-genre=".$result['product_genre']." data-status=".$result['product_status']." data-imagen=".$result['product_imagen']." data-target='#editProductModal'>
```

Hasta aquí todo debería ir bien, pero cuando voy a revisar el codigo en el HTML veo que las variables que trae desde la BD y que tienen espacios las separa de forma que no permite su funcionamiento, codigo html:

```
<input type="button" name="btnEditarProduct" value="Editar" class="btn btn-outline-dark btnEditarProduct" data-toggle="modal" data-id="2" data-name="Bolso" de="" cuero="" data-reference="200" data-desc="Bolso" cuerpo="" hecho="" en="" materiales="" sinteticos="" para="" ayudar="" a="" la="" preservación="" vida="" animal,="" además="" un="" tema="" juvenil="" data-price="350000" data-talla="1" data-cate="1" data-genre="1" data-status="1" data-imagen="images/WhatsApp" image="" 2020-04-02="" at="" 7.56.03="" pm(2).jpeg="" data-target="#editProductModal">
```

De ante mano agradezco si alguien me puede ayudar a eliminar esos espacios que se crean automaticamente en las variables de los "data"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al concatenar solo estás cerrando las comillas dobles y pones la variable, pero todos los valores necesitan estar delimitados, si el producto es "Bolso de cuero" con tu código quedaría así:

```
<input ... data-name=Bolso de cuero ...>
```

Como no tiene comillas entonces te separa las palabras como si fueran otros atributos, debería ser así:

```
<input ... data-name'Bolso de cuero' ...>
```

Fíjate que estoy poniendo comillas sencillas porque así es como lo estás trabajando y todo el botón completo, finalmente iría así:

```
$boton = "<input type='button' name='btnEditarProduct' value='Editar'
    class='btn btn-outline-dark btnEditarProduct'
    data-toggle='modal' data-id='".$result['product_id']."'
    data-name='".$result['product_name']."'
    data-reference='".$result['reference']."'
    data-desc='".$result['product_desc']."'
    data-price='".$result['product_price']."'
    data-talla='".$result['product_talla']."'
    data-cate='".$result['product_cate']."'
    data-genre='".$result['product_genre']."'
    data-status='".$result['product_status']."'
    data-imagen='".$result['product_imagen']."'
    data-target='#editProductModal'>";
```